# How to make effective use of the Linux Kernel Documentation directory?

Tags: documentation, linux-kernel

This may seem like a kind of amorphous question, but how can you get the most of the Linux Kernel Documentation directory?

I noticed on the Linux Cross Reference that [there is a DocBook directory](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.28/Documentation/DocBook/).  How do I build it, use it and is it at all useful?  What other ways are there to make efficient use of this directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the various make targets are documented if you try "make help" at the top of the src tree. In the case of the DocBook stuff there are multiple targets, for example try:

```
make htmldocs
```

Oh and yes it is useful stuff and will probably be the most upto date reference around. A lot of the DocBook stuff extracts documentation on the various functions straight from the kernel source tree annotations.

Comment: How up to date is the info in the generated DocBook dir?  I noticed some of it looked pretty old.  For example, the guide to writing USB drivers is from 2001.  I'm sure plenty has changed since then.

Comment: The headline dates on the document may well be 2001 but if you look at the revision history in GIT ( http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=history;f=Documentation/DocBook/writing_usb_driver.tmpl;hb=HEAD) you see changes are being made.

If you look at the template files themselves you'll see a lot of the DocBook info is pulled straight from the source tree where there are JavaDoc style comments. These comments get updated as APIs get changed.